# How can we use one div one multiple places in View in Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

How can we use one `div` on multiple places in View in `MVC`.
Suppose I have declared one `div` and just call that `div` in multiple frames in Views razor in `MVC`.

Comment: is there any other option because only have to  call one table multiple times,so don't need to use partial views,so just can use section

Comment: It is really hard to see what you mean. Sample of resulting HTML and how it relates to "multiple frames" (assuming IFrames) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using of partial view for you requirement. So the `div` you want to show many place will be part of `partial view` with its own `ViewDataDictionary`.

**Partial Views**

A partial view enables you to define a view that will be rendered inside a parent view. Partial views are implemented as ASP.NET user controls (.ascx).
When a partial view is instantiated, it gets its own copy of the `ViewDataDictionary` object that is available to the parent view. 
The partial view therefore has access to the data of the parent view. However, if the partial view updates the data, those updates affect only the partial view's ViewData object. The parent view's data is not changed.

[Check this for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Or**

Another way is using `jQuery` to get `div` and inject where it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view in `Shared` folder. Put your common HTML there in that partial view. Use `@Html.Partial("_SharedPartialViewName")` wherever you want that common html.

You can also learn implementation from this URL
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC